# facebook, la nueva pestaña de mi aplicacion no se ve en celulares

Tags: facebook

He creado una pestaña en una página de Facebook con contenido personalizado desde un servidor externo .. se ve perfectamente en desktop, pero en el celular no aparece siquiera la pestaña y no logro encontrar en FB developers detalles sobre esto.... como puedo hacer que la nueva pestaña se vea también en móviles..
La verdad no creo que sea problemas del código .. uso la API de javascript.

Pueden ver la aplicación desde DeskTop en https://www.facebook.com/studioqatro/app/1777986842510245/
Pero si trato de acceder desde un movil, me dice que la página no se puede mostrar porque el enlace no está disponible, luego considero que debe ser algo en la configuración de Facebook que impide mostrar esa pestaña en dispositios móviles

Comment: Bienvenido de preferencia, para entender mejor tu pregunta puedas [edit] la pregunta y mostrar el codigo, pudieras leer [mcve]

Comment: elapez te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta para evitar sea cerrada**, saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las Page Tabs personalizadas solamente estan soportadas en Desktop Web.

De momento no hay soporte para ellas en dispositivos mobile. Esto es mencionado en https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs :

> These custom Page tabs load content from your webserver using an iframe. Page tabs will only be displayed in the web UI. Mobile custom tabs are not supported at this time.

Comment: Fantástico ... nunca encontré esta info entre los contenidos en español ... te agradezco mucho !!!!  al menos ya tengo que argumentar.

Comment: Acabo de leer que han puesto en espera mi pregunta  ... quizás no se tomaron la molestia de ver que ya alguién me había dado la respuesta concreta y correcta ... simplemente las pestañas personalizadas no están soportadas en Dispositivos móviles